# Is it possible to restrict dragging ghost image to boundaries in HTML5 drag and drop API?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

When a draggable element is being dragged in a scrollable div. I want to restrict the ghost image at the boundaries of the scrollable div. Currently, when I am moving out of the boundaries, it is not scrolling which is a very bad experience.

I need a similar effect in drag and drop HTML5 API.
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: What code have you got already?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't write any code for positioning the ghost image. But I have this draggable element built. I need to restrict the ghost image in the bordered parent box.
https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-drop-kz05n?file=/src/index.js:671-675

I am not sure if this is possible. I am planning to implement drag and drop with mouse events if drag and drop API does not provide this flexibility.

Comment: I cant really see a way you can implement it using the drag and drop API

Comment: I see! Atleast, can I make it to scroll as soon as it crosses the boundaries?

Comment: I was talking about this effect
https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-snowflake-zubw8

As soon as we cross the boundaries, it keeps scrolling